# Finding percentage on a sub-query with different where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the percentage completed on a table with a sub-query. I can successfully get the value I need using the following, but I am concerned that I am unnecessarily using two queries to get there when one (or a join) would do:

```
SELECT (        
CAST((SELECT COUNT(WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID]) 
FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
WHERE WO.[LOT_ID] = 501 AND WO.[DRY_RUN_FLAG] != 1 
AND WO.[COMPLETED_DATE] IS NOT NULL AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 2) AS float) 
/ 
(CAST((SELECT COUNT(WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID]) 
FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
WHERE WO.[LOT_ID] = 501 AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 2) as Float))
) * 100 AS PERCENT_ROUGH_COMPLETED
```

Specifically, my concern is in the where clause.  I am repeating the exact same query except for the where conditions.  Could this be accomplished with a JOIN on the same table? Multiple joins are confusing me and SQL is one of my weakest skills. I feel like this query could be tightened up because I am going to have to repeat this in a much larger query.

EDIT

By using CASE I was able to configure the larger SQL query properly. I have never written a query this complex before, so forgive if it looks too complicated:

```
 SELECT L.[LOT_ID]
 ,L.[LOT_NUMBER]
 ,L.[JOBSITE_ID]
 ,L.[PHASE_ID]
 ,L.[MODEL_ID]
 ,M.[SQUARE_FOOTAGE]
 ,M.[MODEL_NAME]
 ,P.[PHASE_NAME]

 -- Case 1
 ,CASE 
    WHEN P.[ROUGH_SCHEDULE_FLAG] != 0 
  THEN 
(SELECT (SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN WO.[DRY_RUN_FLAG] <> 1 AND WO.[COMPLETED_DATE] IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO 
JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
WHERE WO.[LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID] AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 1) * 100)
  ELSE 0 
  END AS ROUGH_PERCENT_COMPLETED,

  -- Case 2
  CASE 
    WHEN P.[INTERIOR_SCHEDULE_FLAG] != 0 
  THEN 
(SELECT (SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN WO.[DRY_RUN_FLAG] <> 1 AND WO.[COMPLETED_DATE] IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO 
JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
WHERE WO.[LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID] AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 2) * 100)
  ELSE 0 
  END AS INTERIOR_PERCENT_COMPLETED,

  -- Case 3
  CASE 
    WHEN P.[WASH_SCHEDULE_FLAG] != 0 
  THEN 
(SELECT (SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN WO.[DRY_RUN_FLAG] <> 1 AND WO.[COMPLETED_DATE] IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO 
JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
WHERE WO.[LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID] AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 3) * 100)
  ELSE 0 
  END AS WASH_PERCENT_COMPLETED  

 FROM [NCH].[nch].[LOT] L
 JOIN [NCH].[nch].[MODEL] M ON L.[MODEL_ID] = M.[MODEL_ID]
 JOIN [NCH].[nch].[PHASE] P ON L.[PHASE_ID] = P.[PHASE_ID]
```

WHERE L.[JOBSITE_ID] = 1502

[image: result set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `CASE`. In my opinion is better to use numeric(decimal) instead of `float`. `float` is an approximate datatype that can lead to wrong results. You can read more about this [here](http://www.sparkhound.com/blog/five-scariest-sql-server-data-types).

```
WITH calculations as
(
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN WO.[LOT_ID] = 501 
            AND WO.[DRY_RUN_FLAG] != 1 
            AND WO.[COMPLETED_DATE] IS NOT NULL 
            AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 2 
            AND WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 --the last condition is to simulate COUNT(WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID])
        ELSE 0
        END AS part1
       ,CASE
            WHEN WO.[LOT_ID] = 501 
            AND T.[TASK_TYPE_ID] = 2
            AND WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 --the last condition is to simulate COUNT(WO.[WORK_ORDER_ID])
        ELSE 0
        END AS part2
    FROM [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] WO 
    JOIN [NCH].[nch].[TASK] T 
        ON WO.[TASK_ID] = T.[TASK_ID] 
)
SELECT
    (cast(sum(part1) as numeric(18,6)) / cast(sum(part2) as numeric(18,6))) * 100 as calculation
from calculations
```

Comment: CASE is the missing SQL skill I needed - Thank you for showing me that - this helps me structure the larger query I needed.  Please see the update for that monstrosity.

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify this to:

```
select avg(case when wo.dry_run_flalg <> 1 and
                     wo.completed_date is not null
                then 1.0 else 0
           end) as ratio
from [NCH].[nch].[WORK_ORDER] wo join
     [NCH].[nch].[TASK] t
     on wo.[TASK_ID] = t.[TASK_ID] 
where wo.lot_id = 501 and
      wo.work_order_id is not null and
      t.task_type_id = 2
```

Comment: This is much simpler and would simplify my case statements.  I will update my larger query